# MVC Razor The model item passed into the dictionary is of type List String, but this dictionary requires IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    [Column]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
TestModel[] metadata = context.GetTable<TestModel>().ToArray();


return View(itemsToShow.ToList());
```

the name column and sorts it alphabethically on user selection which works fine (have tested it in debug mode - for example if user selects 'd' it only will display the items starting with 'd'.)

The problem is when i add "@model IEnumerable" and foreach loop in the view I get the error.

Comment: Your `items` collection is of type `List<string>`, not `List<TestModel>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your view is expecting a type of `IEnumerable<TestModel>` for the model but you are passing in `IList<String>` as the error message indicates.

It looks like you shouldn't be projecting `metadata` to an `IList<String>` in your controller and passing to the view but instead should be filtering `metadata` like

```
IEnumerable<TestModel> metadata = context.GetTable<TestModel>().ToArray();

var itemsToShow = string.IsNullOrEmpty (page) 
    ? metadata 
    : metadata.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(page, true, null));

ViewData["currentPage"] = page ?? string.Empty;

return View(itemsToShow.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you call `.ToList()` on your `itemsToShow` ? (i think it is only a duplication)

Change `List<string> items` to `IEnumerable<string> items` and remove `.ToList()` from last line